# Facing Cors error using apollo client from react app

Tags: apollo-client

Apollo-Client, facing cors error, I set fetchOptions, then content-type is defaulted to text/plain. Not sure how to resolve cors error. Please help me on this.
If I set fetchoptions, headers are defaulted, not setting custom headers & cors error.

```
const apiEndPoint = new HttpLink({
  uri: End_Point.GRAPHQL,
  fetchOptions:{
    mode: 'no-cors'
  }
})
const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  // add the authorization to the headers
  operation.setContext(({ headers = {} }) => ({
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      authorization: "testToken",
    }
  }));

  return forward(operation);
})
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: concat(middleware,apiEndPoint),
 
});
```